# How to integrate Ethereum with MATLAB？

Tags: contract-development, external-api

As the computation on Ethereum is expansive, I want do some matrix calculation off-chain. However, it is confused that how to transmit data between Ethereum and other software (like MATLAB)?. Is there any convenient solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the matrix manipulations on python instead, using [web3.py](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py)
I hope this helps.